# monotonic function in SAS

Tags: sas

I tried to used 'monotonic'function in SAS to number the rows and then select e.g >=5000.
When I used below I get the an error. Could someone know how to use this function correctly.

`````
select a.* work.table a,
       works.tables b
       where a.id = b.id
       and monotonic() a.id>=5000
guit;````

Thanks
`````

Comment: Your query is wrong beyond the monotonic portion, please make sure the base functionality works and include any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is wrong beyond the monotonic portion (missing `from`, commas in wrong place, spelling mistake in `quit`, (subjective) no join type).

Here's an example of how it can be used:

```
proc sql;
select * from sashelp.class 
where monotonic() < 5;
quit;
```

EDIT:  making assumptions, select the first 5000 rows.

```
proc sql;
select a.* , monotonic() as row_num
from work.table a full join
       works.tables b
       on a.id = b.id
       where monotonic() <=5000;
quit;
```

Comment: To be clear my query looks like below: